# Remembering fileName after application closes

Tags: c#, wpf

In my C# WPF application, I want to incorporate something like 'last used file remember feature'

So, if previously the user has opened some file (and remembered it), the next time on opening the application, the file should open automatically.

Other than writing the path of the file, is there any other way to this?
If I have to write the path to the file, what's the location mostly used to store these temp remembered file paths and keep away from user? (some environment folder?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify User Settings to store some information. In the Solution Explorer go to your project and in the folder Properties, double-click the settings-file. In here you can set the Name, Type, Scope and Value. Just set the Name to "FileName", Type to "string", scope to "User" and leave the Value empty or set a default value if you want. Save the settings-file. In code you can set and get the value like this:

```
//get
var name = Properties.Settings.Default.FileName;

//set
Properties.Settings.Default.FileName = "....";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ont of this .NET features:

- [User Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

They save settings with different scope. I guess you can use application settings.

Comment: Application Settings won't do, they are read-only at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there are three location available for this kind of configuration.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

The first is to be used if the configuration applies to the whole application
The second is to be used if the configuration applies only to the current user (roaming)
The third  is to be used if the configuration applies only to the current user (local)

In each case you should create a subfolder in these paths with the name of your company and then the name of your product. Never save directly there.
I prefer to stay away from changing config files from code although I must admit it is very convenient